# Telerik submenu in radmenu cutoff from screen

Tags: .net, telerik, submenu, radmenu

I have Telerik RAD menu on my aspx page. The menu bind dynamically starting from right to left.

But if I have only one parent menu then it submenus start cutting off the screen, the problem is no longer persists if we have more than one parent menu(in this case Telerik classes handle it automatically). Also I didn't use any custom class over it.

I have attached screenshots of error menu and expected menu.

[image: Error RAD Menu]

[image: Expected RAD Menu]

here is my RAD Menu code in aspx page:

```
 <telerik:RadMenu runat="server" ID="rdmnMainMenu" EnableAutoScroll="true" EnableRootItemScroll="true" EnableRoundedCorners="true" EnableShadows="true" EnableOverlay="true"    OnItemCreated="rdmnMainMenu_ItemCreated" Skin="Default" AutoSkinMode="false" OnClientItemClicked="mnuMain_clicked" OnClientItemClosed="mnuMain_closed" Width="100%" OnClientMouseOut="mnuMain_MouseOut" OnClientMouseOver="mnuMain_MouseOver" ClientKey="mnuMain_app" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property to the RAD Menu:

```
DefaultGroupSettings-OffsetX="0"
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have a control (usually a radgrid) that is using a different RenderMode than your menu item.  Make sure your controls are using the same RenderMode.